# Can't see quandl in python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, quandl

I installed `quandl module` with `pip3 install quandl` and received a msg for successful installation. But I cannot see it in the python module list. And when run a code with `import quandl`, get an error:

```
File "Regression.py", line 2, in <module>
    import quandl
ImportError: No module named quandl.
```

I tried several things but wasn't successful. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here you can see the complete error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in >run
   prefix=options.prefix_path,
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in >install
  requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in >uninstall
 paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in >remove
 renames(path, new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in >renames
 shutil.move(old, new)
File >"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py>", line 302, in move
 copy2(src, real_dst)
 File >"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py>", line 131, in copy2
   copystat(src, dst)
File >"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py>", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-sk4mSc->uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/pyth>on/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: What specifically have you tried?

Comment: You say you've installed it for Python 3 with `pip3 install` but your question is tagged as Python 2, so perhaps you're trying to import it with the wrong Python version.

Comment: @Jerrybibo I followed the instructions already worked for people for example: added quandl library to python library folder and tried to install it with its path. I deleted the other libraries which sound make a problem and install them again.

Comment: did you try `pip2 install quandl` to install as a python2 library. edit: it also looks like you are using the system python which is generally discouraged. You should use the python2 interpreter which can be installed via homebrew

Comment: @ Arthur Vigil I just tried >pip2 install quandl. The same error:( I installed python through homebrew